# Partial update of PouchDB document with the 'delta-pouch' plugin using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, pouchdb

I'm trying to get the [delta-pouch plugin](https://github.com/redgeoff/delta-pouch) to work with my [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com) setup on my AngularJS app.

My data service in Angular looks as following:

```
myApp.factory('DataService', ['$q', '$rootScope', 'PouchDB', function($q, $rootScope, PouchDB) {
  return {
    add: function(doc) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      PouchDB.post(doc, function(err, res) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
          } else {
            deferred.resolve(res)
          }
        });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    list: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      return PouchDB.allDocs({include_docs: true, descending: true}, function(err, res) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
          } else {
            deferred.resolve(res)
          }
        });
      });
      return deferred.promise;
    },

    update: function(obj) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
        return PouchDB.save(obj, function(err, res) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err)
          } else {
            deferred.resolve(res)
          }
        });
        });
     return deferred.promise;
    },

    get: function(id) {
        return PouchDB.get(id);
    },

    destroy: function() {
        PouchDB.destroy();
    }
  }
}]);
```

`list` and `add` are working fine, but calling `save` returns in the following error. This is the

```
Error: 'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Promise(function (fulfill) {
    db.post(doc).then(function (doc) {
      fulfill(doc);
    });
  })')
```

To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what I am doing, as I am quite new to Angular. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've released an all-in-one angularjs binding called [factoryng](https://github.com/redgeoff/factoryng) that you can use to incorporate delta pouch (or vanilla pouch) into your angular code. I think it will really help you get delta pouch working in your angularjs code.

Also, I'd recommend taking a look at the [Contacts example](https://github.com/redgeoff/factoryng/blob/master/examples/contacts/contact.js) as it covers all the CRUD operations. Let me know if you're still having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you seeing this? In your Karma tests (i.e. PhantomJS)? It looks like `Promise` is not being implemented correctly in your browser, which means you may need to use an explicit Promise shim like [this one](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise).

Comment: Just seeing this in the browser (developer console). The compiled build of the plugin is:
https://gist.github.com/dandoen/1a8cfe1b0cbe76eb34d7#file-pouchdb-delta-pouch-js-L42